# Node.js: Serious Memory Leak Bug in newer versions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, memory, memory-leaks

## What's the problem?

First I tought something is wrong with my node.js modules or codes because as I visited my pages the memory decreased after every visit and it was not released back. After hours of debugging, I couldn't find any problem, so I tried the default node.js server example to see if the problem is in my code or in node.js itself.

### How to repeat the problem:

So I created the server like this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80);
console.log('Server running at port 80');
```

I visited `mydomain.com` and hit refresh repeatedly, and the free memory just kept dropping, and even after I release the refreshing, the memory remains at the same level, so node.js keeps it.

### So what is wrong here?

**Environment**

I was testing on `ubuntu 12`, `max os x 10.8.3` with `node v0.9.0`, `node v0.10.0`, `v0.10.2`, `v0.10.4`, `v0.11.1` where the problem exists and on `node v0.8.21` where it works properly, that's why I say it maybe be a bug in newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

`V8` will call **GC** when **needed** and the memory usage should be decreased at that point.

To make sure that the **GC** process is working fine, I suggest you to run **node** with `--expose-gc` argument and check the memory usage with something like this:

```
var http = require('http'),
    util = require('util');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');

    global.gc();
    console.log('Memory Usage:');
    console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));
}).listen(8080); // changed the port to 8080 because I didn't want to run the server as root

console.log('Server running at port 8080');
```

Comment: I already know the memory usage with `htop`. I tried `global.gc()` too and outputs the same thing :), any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Comment: I run the code above (actually moved `global.gc()` and memory usage print code to a `setInterval` callback) on **Node v0.10.4** under **OS X 10.8.3**. After about 1 hour of flooding the server with HTTP requests, the **rss** value freezed completely and **heapUsed** value became limited to a certain range (actually it was from the beginning.)